# How to run multiple declare statements in oracle sql tool?

Tags: sql, oracle

I had the run the multiple declare statements one after the other in sql tool for the below

```
DECLARE v_count NUMBER; BEGIN SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count FROM DTLS WHERE LOGONID = 'l@k.com'; IF v_count = 0 THEN INSERT INTO DTLS (LOGONID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ROLENAME, EMAIL, CID ) VALUES ('l@k.com', 'Ls', 'Dva', '805ser', 'l@k.com'); ELSE UPDATE DTLS SET ROLENAME = '80ar User' WHERE LOGONID = 'l@k.com';  END IF;END;
DECLARE v_count NUMBER; BEGIN SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count FROM DTLS WHERE LOGONID = 'n@s.com'; IF v_count = 0 THEN INSERT INTO DTLS (LOGONID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ROLENAME, EMAIL, CID ) VALUES ('n@s.com', 'Pt', 'Ns', '509User', 'n@s.com'); ELSE UPDATE DTLS SET ROLENAME = '50_User' WHERE LOGONID = 'n@s.com';  END IF;END;
DECLARE v_count NUMBER; BEGIN SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count FROM DTLS WHERE LOGONID = 'J@y.com'; IF v_count = 0 THEN INSERT INTO DTLS (LOGONID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ROLENAME, EMAIL, CID) VALUES ('J@y.com', 'Jn', 'Re', '300nly', 'J@y.com'); ELSE UPDATE DTLS SET ROLENAME = '300ly' WHERE LOGONID = 'J@y.com';  END IF;END;
DECLARE v_count NUMBER; BEGIN SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count FROM DTLS WHERE LOGONID = 'a@r.com'; IF v_count = 0 THEN INSERT INTO DTLS (LOGONID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ROLENAME, EMAIL, CID) VALUES ('a@r.com', 'A', 'rczyk', '300ser', 'a@r.com'); ELSE UPDATE DTLS SET ROLENAME = '300' WHERE LOGONID = 'a@r.com';  END IF;END;
```

How could i do it?

Comment: Which tool? Oracle SQL Developer?

Comment: Your `INSERT` lists 6 columns but only provides 5 values.

Comment: @MT0 its typo mistake ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use PL/SQL or multiple statements, use a single `MERGE` SQL statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO DTLS dst
USING (
  WITH data (LOGONID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ROLENAME, new_rolename, EMAIL, CID) AS (
    SELECT 'l@k.com', 'Ls', 'Dva', '805ser', '80ar User', 'l@k.com', 'something' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'n@s.com', 'Pt', 'Ns', '509User', '50_User', 'n@s.com', 'something' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'J@y.com', 'Jn', 'Re', '300nly', '300ly', 'J@y.com', 'something' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a@r.com', 'A', 'rczyk', '300ser', '300', 'a@r.com', 'something' FROM DUAL
  )
  SELECT * FROM data
) src
ON (src.logonid = dst.logonid)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (LOGONID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ROLENAME, EMAIL, CID)
  VALUES (src.LOGONID, src.FIRSTNAME, src.LASTNAME, src.ROLENAME, src.EMAIL, src.CID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE 
  SET ROLENAME = src.new_rolename;
```

If you want to fix your script (don't, its inefficient to run multiple single-row statements context-switched from PL/SQL when you could do a single SQL statement) then you can use a single PL/SQL block:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count FROM DTLS WHERE LOGONID = 'l@k.com';
  IF v_count = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO DTLS (LOGONID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ROLENAME, EMAIL, CID )
    VALUES ('l@k.com', 'Ls', 'Dva', '805ser', 'l@k.com', 'something');
  ELSE
    UPDATE DTLS SET ROLENAME = '80ar User' WHERE LOGONID = 'l@k.com';
  END IF;

  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count FROM DTLS WHERE LOGONID = 'n@s.com';
  IF v_count = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO DTLS (LOGONID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ROLENAME, EMAIL, CID )
    VALUES ('n@s.com', 'Pt', 'Ns', '509User', 'n@s.com', 'something');
  ELSE
    UPDATE DTLS SET ROLENAME = '50_User' WHERE LOGONID = 'n@s.com';
  END IF;

  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count FROM DTLS WHERE LOGONID = 'J@y.com';
  IF v_count = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO DTLS (LOGONID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ROLENAME, EMAIL, CID)
    VALUES ('J@y.com', 'Jn', 'Re', '300nly', 'J@y.com', 'something');
  ELSE
    UPDATE DTLS SET ROLENAME = '300ly' WHERE LOGONID = 'J@y.com';
  END IF;

  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count FROM DTLS WHERE LOGONID = 'a@r.com';
  IF v_count = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO DTLS (LOGONID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ROLENAME, EMAIL, CID)
    VALUES ('a@r.com', 'A', 'rczyk', '300ser', 'a@r.com', 'something');
  ELSE
    UPDATE DTLS SET ROLENAME = '300' WHERE LOGONID = 'a@r.com';
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Or, put the PL/SQL statement terminator `/` on a blank line between each PL/SQL block to terminate each statement:

```sql
DECLARE v_count NUMBER; BEGIN SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count FROM DTLS WHERE LOGONID = 'l@k.com'; IF v_count = 0 THEN INSERT INTO DTLS (LOGONID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ROLENAME, EMAIL, CID ) VALUES ('l@k.com', 'Ls', 'Dva', '805ser', 'l@k.com', 'something'); ELSE UPDATE DTLS SET ROLENAME = '80ar User' WHERE LOGONID = 'l@k.com';  END IF;END;
/
DECLARE v_count NUMBER; BEGIN SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count FROM DTLS WHERE LOGONID = 'n@s.com'; IF v_count = 0 THEN INSERT INTO DTLS (LOGONID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ROLENAME, EMAIL, CID ) VALUES ('n@s.com', 'Pt', 'Ns', '509User', 'n@s.com', 'something'); ELSE UPDATE DTLS SET ROLENAME = '50_User' WHERE LOGONID = 'n@s.com';  END IF;END;
/
DECLARE v_count NUMBER; BEGIN SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count FROM DTLS WHERE LOGONID = 'J@y.com'; IF v_count = 0 THEN INSERT INTO DTLS (LOGONID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ROLENAME, EMAIL, CID) VALUES ('J@y.com', 'Jn', 'Re', '300nly', 'J@y.com', 'something'); ELSE UPDATE DTLS SET ROLENAME = '300ly' WHERE LOGONID = 'J@y.com';  END IF;END;
/
DECLARE v_count NUMBER; BEGIN SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count FROM DTLS WHERE LOGONID = 'a@r.com'; IF v_count = 0 THEN INSERT INTO DTLS (LOGONID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ROLENAME, EMAIL, CID) VALUES ('a@r.com', 'A', 'rczyk', '300ser', 'a@r.com', 'something'); ELSE UPDATE DTLS SET ROLENAME = '300' WHERE LOGONID = 'a@r.com';  END IF;END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6Bqar-DP)

Answer (score 0):

To run multiple PL/SQL blocks in one call, add `BEGIN` to the front and add `END;` at the end:

```
BEGIN
   DECLARE v_count NUMBER; BEGIN SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count FROM DTLS WHERE LOGONID = 'l@k.com'; IF v_count = 0 THEN INSERT INTO DTLS (LOGONID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ROLENAME, EMAIL, CID ) VALUES ('l@k.com', 'Ls', 'Dva', '805ser', 'l@k.com'); ELSE UPDATE DTLS SET ROLENAME = '80ar User' WHERE LOGONID = 'l@k.com';  END IF;END;
   DECLARE v_count NUMBER; BEGIN SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count FROM DTLS WHERE LOGONID = 'n@s.com'; IF v_count = 0 THEN INSERT INTO DTLS (LOGONID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ROLENAME, EMAIL, CID ) VALUES ('n@s.com', 'Pt', 'Ns', '509User', 'n@s.com'); ELSE UPDATE DTLS SET ROLENAME = '50_User' WHERE LOGONID = 'n@s.com';  END IF;END;
   DECLARE v_count NUMBER; BEGIN SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count FROM DTLS WHERE LOGONID = 'J@y.com'; IF v_count = 0 THEN INSERT INTO DTLS (LOGONID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ROLENAME, EMAIL, CID) VALUES ('J@y.com', 'Jn', 'Re', '300nly', 'J@y.com'); ELSE UPDATE DTLS SET ROLENAME = '300ly' WHERE LOGONID = 'J@y.com';  END IF;END;
   DECLARE v_count NUMBER; BEGIN SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count FROM DTLS WHERE LOGONID = 'a@r.com'; IF v_count = 0 THEN INSERT INTO DTLS (LOGONID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, ROLENAME, EMAIL, CID) VALUES ('a@r.com', 'A', 'rczyk', '300ser', 'a@r.com'); ELSE UPDATE DTLS SET ROLENAME = '300' WHERE LOGONID = 'a@r.com';  END IF;END;
END;
```

Anonymous blocks can be infinitely nested, and this is the easiest way to create that nesting. Depending on which environment you run the code in, you may need to add a `/` at the end. For example, in SQL*Plus, the slash would be necessary to run the code. But if you're running through JDBC, the slash should not be included.

MT0 had some good ideas for other ways to rewrite multiple anonymous blocks. Those methods could improve performance (a single statement), shrink the code (rewrite everything as a single block without nesting), or give more control over running individual commands (putting slashes between blocks). But it's often easiest to take the entire chunk of code and simply add a `BEGIN` and `END` to the entire block.